# CakePHP not picking up a javascript

Tags: cakephp

I am a totally noob at CakePHP and have been dealing with this site update from traditional php to CakePHP. In the old website there was a folder for javascript and in there, there was a file called paging.js, then, at then end of where i was doing the table loops and stuff you would add this

```
  echo '<div id="pageNavPosition"></div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>';    



  echo "<script type='text/javascript'><!--
        var pagerAdmin = new PagerAdmin('results', 5); 
        pagerAdmin.init(); 
        pagerAdmin.showPageNav('pagerAdmin', 'pageNavPosition'); 
        pagerAdmin.showPage(1);
    //--></script>";
  }
```

In that website works perfectly, it shows only 5 records and with pagination. But now here in cake PHP I have thi code in my view but its not picking up that portion of code

```
  <?php

        echo '<div><h3>Admin - Update Data</h3><p>To update data click on name</p></div>';
        print("<table id='results'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Description</th></tr>");

         $i =0;
         foreach ($dishes as $key => $dish):

         print("<tr>");   
         print("<td width='20px'>");
         echo '<p style="font-size:14px; color:blue; padding:0;">'.$dishes[$i]['Dish']['id'].'</p>';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$dishes[$i]['Dish']['dish_name'].'" value="'.$dishes[$i]['Dish']['id'].'" id="DishDishId" />';
         print("</td>");          
         print("<td width='10px'>");
         print("<img class='custom_rate' alt='' src='/myweb/img/".$dishes[$i]['Dish']['dish_image']."' />");
         print("</td>");
         print("<td width='100px'>");
         print("<a href='index.php?form_type=admin_manager&id=".$dishes[$i]['Dish']['id']."'>".$dishes[$i]['Dish']['dish_name']."</a> ");
         print("</td>");
         print("<td width='100px'>");
         print($dishes[$i]['Dish']['dish_price']);
         print("</td>");
         print("<td width='100px'>");
         print($dishes[$i]['Dish']['dish_disc']);
         print("</td>");
         print("</tr>");
         $i++; 
         endforeach;
          print("</table>");

          if($i> 5)
          {
             echo '<div id="pageNavPosition"></div>
                   <div>&nbsp;</div>';    



            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>"  ;
            echo   "var pagerAdmin = new PagerAdmin('results', 5);"; 
            echo   'pagerAdmin.init();';
            echo   "pagerAdmin.showPageNav('pagerAdmin', 'pageNavPosition');"; 
            echo   'pagerAdmin.showPage(1);';
            echo '</script>";';
        }


          ?>
```

Any idea how i can make this work again? .Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does your js console says ?

Comment: what do you mean in view source? it's there.. it is added there.. but now sure why it would be picked up

Comment: what do you have in jquery.js? shouldnt that be added before jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js ? look at fire bug errors

Comment: @user710502 Your browser JavaScript Console, see if you get any JavaScript error.

Comment: There were a few errors there but i fixed them until no more errors.. and nothing ... hmmm

Comment: Ok I fixed it, I put that code in a js file and called like this

echo $this->Html->script('myjasfile.js');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this issue, you just need to create a separate .js file and place it in the webroot/js folder with your js code. Then reference it as follows

```
echo $this->Html->script('myjasfile.js');
```